# Detect when a keyframe is set on an attribute in Maya?

Tags: python, maya, mel, pymel

I'm trying to trigger a script to run when a keyframe is set in Maya.  I'm currently using `scriptJob`'s to trigger scripts on the `timeChanged` event and when certain attributes change, but I've not found an event for when a keyframe is set.

Is there a way to detect when a keyframe is set in maya and trigger a script to run when this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can relay on MAnimMessage [Docs](http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2016/ENU/?guid=__py_ref_class_open_maya_anim_1_1_m_anim_message_html)  .This callback can help you to find the keyframe action and plug a callback eg :

```
OpenMayaAnim.MAnimMessage.addAnimKeyframeEditedCallback( obj.addKeyframeDelta, None)
```